# Access fresh REDUX state in function of React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, state

I'm using React and React-Redux-Toolkit and difficulties accessing the updated state from within a function.

I have a custom React Component which I pass a variable of my state:

```js
const { useEffect, useState } = React;
  
const ExternalComponent = ({ func }) => {
  func();
  
  return (
    <div></div>
  );
};
  
const Component = ({ state }) => {
  console.log("Component", state);

  const someFunction = () => {
    console.log("state", state);
  };

  return (
    <ExternalComponent func={someFunction} />
  );
};

const Page = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    setState(true);
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <Component state={state} />
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Page />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<body>
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/babel" src="main.js"></script>
</body>
```

On initial page render the component prints `Component undefined`, because `state` is yet `undefined`, which is understandable and not the problem.

When I update `state` by any means, the component re-renders and prints `Component <the change>`, which is also as expected.

However, `someFunction()` will not update and still print the old `state`, which is still `undefined`.

How do I get `someFunction()` to "update", i.e. print the **updated** `state`?

Edit: Typo

Edit2: I created a code snippet in which everything works as expected. However, in my actual code I'm using [PaypalButtons](https://www.paypal.com/buttons/smart?flowloggingId=151b954e50daa), where I pass `someFunction` to `createOrder`. I'm not sure how PaypalButtons works and why `someFunction` would not get updated.

Edit3: I'm using [paypal-react-js](https://github.com/paypal/react-paypal-js)

Comment: Based on above code, it should print fine. Are you wrapping someFunction in `useCallback` ? If not, can you share how `someFunction` is called from `SomeThirdPartyComponent`

Comment: Please provide a REPRODUCIBLE example [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @DennisVash I created a reproducible example, however I couldn't reproduce the problem, because I'm using PaypalButtons

Comment: Seems like an issue with the specific component, without reproducing we can only guess

Comment: @Easwar Thank you for the hint. This was indeed the case. Solution is posted below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you have a stale value. Try using `useCallback`

```
import { useCallback } from 'react';

const Component = ({ statefulVariable }) => {
  console.log("Component", statefulVariable);

  const someFunction = useCallback(() => {
    console.log(statefulVariable);
  }), [statefulVariable]);

  return (
    <SomeThirdPartyComponent callback={someFunction}/>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried using useCallback without any effect. I edited my code snippet and mentioned the fact that I'm using PaypalButtons. I suspect the problem to lay there